# (pyspark) how to make dataframes which have no same user_id mutually

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark

I was trying to collect `2 user_id dataframes` which have no same user_id mutually in pyspark.

[image]

So, I typed some codes below you can see

```py
import  pyspark.sql.functions as f

query = "select * from tb_original"
df_original = spark.sql(query)
df_original = df_original.select("user_id").distinct()

df_a = df_original.sort(f.rand()).limit(10000)
df_a.count()
# df_a: 10000

df_b = df_original.join(df_a,on="user_id",how="left_anti").sort(f.rand()).limit(10000)

df_b.count()
# df_b: 10000

df_a.join(df_b,on="user_id",how="left_anti").count()
# df_a - df_b = 9998
# What?????
```

As a result, `df_a and df_b` have the same 2 user_ids... sometimes 1, or 0.

It looks like no problem with codes. However, this occurs due to lazy action of spark mechanism maybe...

I need to solve this problem for collecting `2 user_id dataframes` which have no same user_id mutually.

Comment: `df_original.join(df_a,on="user_id",how="left_anti")` should have no results because all user_id in df_a should be present in df_original. I don't know why you got 10000. If you want to collect two dataframes uses `df_a.union(df_b).distinct()`

Comment: @mck 10000 is just an example. I need 2 dataframes because those are used by different user groups like the A/B test and the `users in df_a & df_b` shouldn't be duplicated. Therefore, your advice doesn't suit my case.

Comment: @rupert if your distribution is like 60:40 then use the number of group to be 5 and filter 0,1,2 in df_a  and keep 3,4 in df_b . My answer assumes you are trying to have equal split in two columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose `randomSplit` function pyspark supports.

```py
df_a,df_b = df_original.randomSplit([0.6,0.4])

df_a = df_a.limit(10000)
df_a.count()
# 10000

df_b = df_b.limit(10000)
df_b.count()
# 10000

df_a.join(df_b,on="user_id",how="left_anti").count()
# 10000
```

never conflict between df_a and df_b anymore!

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to generate two different set of users from a given pool of users with no overlap you may use this simple trick : =

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
import  pyspark.sql.functions as f

#"Creation of Original DF"
query = "select * from tb_original"
df_original = spark.sql(query)
df_original = df_original.select("user_id").distinct()

df_original =df.withColumn("UNIQUE_ID", monotonically_increasing_id())
number_groups_needed=2  ## you can adjust the number of group you need for your use case
dfa=df_original.filter(df_original.UNIQUE_ID % number_groups_needed ==0) 
dfb=df_original.filter(df_original.UNIQUE_ID % number_groups_needed ==1)

##dfa and dfb will not have any overlap for user_id
```

Ps- if your user_id is itself a integer you don't need to create a new UNIQUE_ID column you can use it directly .